# C# Convert or Cast ExpandoObject to Specific Class Object

Tags: c#, class, casting, typeconverter

I have a problem to cast or convert ExpandoObject to Object that is specific class in C# project.

Class of Object:

```
public class PlayerData {
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public string Phone { get; set; }
   public Money Money { get; set; }
}

public class Money {
   public int Cash { get; set; }
   public int Bank { get; set; }
}
```

When in server sent some data (of type PlayerData) to client side, client see that data in class ExpandoObject. I can use this data as well (like Data.Id, Data.Phone etc.).

In my problem, I need to cast or convert ExpandoObject that I got (It have type PlayerData before) to PlayerData in client side.

Line that cast type :

```
PlayerData MyData = (PlayerData)Data;
```

And it return error :

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

How can I fixed it and cast or convert it correctly?

***Note***
// When I print `Data.GetType()` it return `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`

Comment: If there's a server and a client, there's some method of communication between them. You **don't** solve this problem through `ExpandoObject`, you solve it through proper serialization and deserialization

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot simply cast type like this. The best way to approach it is using `Newtonsoft.Json` library with `SerializeObject` to convert data into string and `DeserializeObject` to convert string into your type

Try this

```
PlayerData player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerData>( JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));
```

Update: for your question in comment about why you cannot cast object like this

You should refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions to understand how C# `Cast` works

In short, If you write

```
PlayerData MyData = (PlayerData)Data;
```

It only works If `PlayerData` is sub class of `Data.GetType()` and here is `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`. But it is not true, so you cannot do this

Comment: It Works. But can you tell me why can't I convert it directly? I'm a new c# programer.

Comment: @PhuminMukem to be honest, I feel hard to explain it in simple way but I update answer with reference about how C# Cast works and hope this helps you

Comment: that is very good solutions, you saved me day

Comment: You can use `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` as well, not only `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert`.

Comment: Your solution worked among lots of solutions. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/).

```
public class Foo {
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public int Baz { get; set; }
    public Foo InnerFoo { get; set; }
}
dynamic foo = new MyDynamicObject();
foo.Bar = 5;
foo.Baz = 6;

var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var result = mapper.Map<Foo>(foo);
result.Bar.ShouldEqual(5);
result.Baz.ShouldEqual(6);

dynamic foo2 = mapper.Map<MyDynamicObject>(result);
foo2.Bar.ShouldEqual(5);
foo2.Baz.ShouldEqual(6);
```

See details [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html).